# Stripe error object object(Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

After inserting card details and confirming Pay, Stripe redirects the page and instead of successfully accepting the transaction it returns the object below as an error. The error URL is `charge.php`.

Does anyone know why it is giving this error?

`object(Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException)#1261 (15) { ["stripeParam":protected]=> string(15) "items[0][price]" ["error":protected]=> object(Stripe\ErrorObject)#1305 (11) { ["charge"]=> NULL ["code"]=> string(16) "resource_missing" ["decline_code"]=> NULL ["doc_url"]=> string(52) "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing" ["message"]=> string(47) "No such price: 'price_1LmxIWFXVdPATSx7vMIkz3vS'" ["param"]=> string(15) "items[0][price]" ["payment_intent"]=> NULL ["payment_method"]=> NULL ["setup_intent"]=> NULL ["source"]=> NULL ["type"]=> string(21) "invalid_request_error" } ["httpBody":protected]=> string(258) "{ "error": { "code": "resource_missing", "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing", "message": "No such price: 'price_1LmxIWFXVdPATSx7vMIkz3vS'", "param": "items[0][price]", "type": "invalid_request_error" } } " ["httpHeaders":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\CaseInsensitiveArray)#1300 (1) { ["container":"Stripe\Util\CaseInsensitiveArray":private]=> array(15) { ["server"]=> string(5) "nginx" ["date"]=> string(29) "Sun, 09 Oct 2022 17:40:41 GMT" ["content-type"]=> string(16) "application/json" ["content-length"]=> string(3) "258" ["access-control-allow-credentials"]=> string(4) "true" ["access-control-allow-methods"]=> string(32) "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE" ["access-control-allow-origin"]=> string(1) "*" ["access-control-expose-headers"]=> string(104) "Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required" ["access-control-max-age"]=> string(3) "300" ["cache-control"]=> string(18) "no-cache, no-store" ["idempotency-key"]=> string(36) "e0a75340-8d0e-46ef-8a8b-37f2290f4392" ["original-request"]=> string(18) "req_i5pk2HJmAGVbix" ["request-id"]=> string(18) "req_i5pk2HJmAGVbix" ["stripe-version"]=> string(10) "2018-09-24" ["strict-transport-security"]=> string(44) "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" } } ["httpStatus":protected]=> int(400) ["jsonBody":protected]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(5) { ["code"]=> string(16) "resource_missing" ["doc_url"]=> string(52) "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing" ["message"]=> string(47) "No such price: 'price_1LmxIWFXVdPATSx7vMIkz3vS'" ["param"]=> string(15) "items[0][price]" ["type"]=> string(21) "invalid_request_error" } } ["requestId":protected]=> string(18) "req_i5pk2HJmAGVbix" ["stripeCode":protected]=> string(16) "resource_missing" ["message":protected]=> string(47) "No such price: 'price_1LmxIWFXVdPATSx7vMIkz3vS'" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(134) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Exception.php" ["line":protected]=> int(38) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(8) { [0]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(140) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Exception.php" ["line"]=> int(35) ["function"]=> string(7) "factory" ["class"]=> string(34) "Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" } [1]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(119) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Requestor.php" ["line"]=> int(215) ["function"]=> string(7) "factory" ["class"]=> string(40) "Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" } [2]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(119) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Requestor.php" ["line"]=> int(177) ["function"]=> string(17) "_specificAPIError" ["class"]=> string(19) "Stripe\ApiRequestor" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" } [3]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(119) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Requestor.php" ["line"]=> int(562) ["function"]=> string(19) "handleErrorResponse" ["class"]=> string(19) "Stripe\ApiRequestor" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [4]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(119) "/home/591121.cloudwa...Requestor.php" ["line"]=> int(124) ["function"]=> string(18) "_interpretResponse" ["class"]=> string(19) "Stripe\ApiRequestor" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [5]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(128) "/home/591121.cloudwa...s/Request.php" ["line"]=> int(80) ["function"]=> string(7) "request" ["class"]=> string(19) "Stripe\ApiRequestor" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [6]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(127) "/home/591121.cloudwa...ns/Create.php" ["line"]=> int(25) ["function"]=> string(14) "_staticRequest" ["class"]=> string(18) "Stripe\ApiResource" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" } [7]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(109) "/home/591121.cloudwa...pe/charge.php" ["line"]=> int(251) ["function"]=> string(6) "create" ["class"]=> string(19) "Stripe\Subscription" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL }`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be passing in a Price ID from a different Stripe account. You should review the accounts you have access to and search for the Price ID (price_1LmxIWFXVdPATSx7vMIkz3vS) in that error message to see which account it came from.

Additionally, if you must make this request on behalf of this account, then you'll want to make sure you're using a Price that is accessible from this account: https://dashboard.stripe.com/products